# Open Refine : Reconciliation with Freebase data based on ORganization Name

Tags: openrefine

I've been following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tsyz3ibYzk

I've been following all the steps, but I noticed that, for my dataset, freebase doesn't suggest any kind of type, like it does for 'movies' in the example.

I have a column of organization names ('Babson College', 'Aspen Institute') are two examples. When I click on 'start reconciliation' --> 'Choose from Wikipedia Namespace', nothing Happens.

I'd appreciate your help!

I am using Open Refine 2.6. I only see query based service

Answer (score 0):

The reconciliation part with freebase is currently broken. See [this isse for more details](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/805)